# Hi I am trying to use git on windows - seems to hang up

Tags: git

Just installed the latest beta release of git and when i try to clone a repository I get
the following:

```
    git clone git@hark.unfuddle.com:hark/quasargit.git
    Initialized empty Git repository in c:/gitproject/quasargit/.git/
    Enter passphrase for key '/c/Documents and Settings/Windows/.ssh/id_rsa':
    remote: Counting objects: 2614, done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1572/1572), done.
    Receiving objects:   1% (33/2614), 3.09 MiB | 28 KiB/s
```

and it stays like that for 30 minutes.

Comment: doesn't this belong to superuser?

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into similar problems with win32 version of git.

Archive the repositary into one file and copy it using some other tool (http, sftp, rsync).

Subsequent push/pull operations will presumably be less traffic-hungry.

Dont forget to manually configure the 'remote' branche.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of speed problem has always been related to other traffic on my network - especially bittorrent for me.

I'm sure it could be caused by a lot of things but you should definitely consider trying again with all other internet-using programs closed.